# Filter objects in an array by a property value - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, javascript-objects

Long story short, I am a beginner trying to build a feature where we receive the users feedback for a particular survey that was sent by email.

The response is an array of objects and undefined values.
Each object has 3 properties: email, surveyId and choice.

I need obtain a new array with no duplicates and no undefined.

Also, the user can only provide one choice for a particular survey, so we can't have 2 objects with the same email and surveyID but with different choices.
The obj with the lowest index will be the first answer and that is the one we want.

Example:

```
const arr = [
  {
    email: 'mynewemail@gmail.com',
    surveyId: '1234',
    choice: 'no'
  },
  undefined,
  {
    email: 'mynewemail@gmail.com',
    surveyId: '1234',
    choice: 'yes'
  },
  {
    email: 'example2@gmail.com',
    surveyId: '1234',
    choice: 'no'
  },
  undefined,
  {
    email: 'mynewemail@gmail.com',
    surveyId: '4567',
    choice: 'no'
  },
  {
    email: 'mynewemail@gmail.com',
    surveyId: '1234',
    choice: 'yes'
  },
  {
    email: 'example@gmail.com',
    surveyId: '7689',
    choice: 'yes'
  }
];
```

Result that I want:

```
filteredArray = [
  {
    email: 'mynewemail@gmail.com',
    surveyId: '1234',
    choice: 'no'
  },
  {
    email: 'example2@gmail.com',
    surveyId: '1234',
    choice: 'no'
  },
  {
    email: 'mynewemail@gmail.com',
    surveyId: '4567',
    choice: 'no'
  },
  {
    email: 'example@gmail.com',
    surveyId: '7689',
    choice: 'yes'
  }
];
```

So removing the undefined is easy:

```
const undefiniedFilteredArr = events.filter(e => e !== undefined);
```

I can also filter the duplicate objects or by using lodash _uniqBy or even using loops and I am sure there are many ways of doing this.

Now, what I can't figure is how to filter the objects that have the same email and surveyId but a different choice and choose the obj with the lowest index. I don't want two different feedbacks from the same email for the same surveyId.

Please note I can add a 4th property called timestamp and use it to prioritize the choice if that makes it easier.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Also, note that I am a beginer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arr = [{ email: 'mynewemail@gmail.com', surveyId: '1234', choice: 'no' }, undefined,{email: 'mynewemail@gmail.com',surveyId: '1234',choice: 'yes'},{email: 'example2@gmail.com',surveyId: '1234',choice: 'no'},undefined,{email: 'mynewemail@gmail.com',surveyId: '4567',choice: 'no'},{email: 'mynewemail@gmail.com',surveyId: '1234',choice: 'yes'},{email: 'example@gmail.com',surveyId: '7689',choice: 'yes'}];

// Filter out undefined
const entries = arr.filter(x => !!x);

// A set to maintain unique combinations of email and surveyId
const set = new Set();

const result = [];

const getUniqueKey = ({email, surveyId}) => email + "||" + surveyId;

for (const entry of entries) {
  const key = getUniqueKey(entry);
  if (!set.has(key)) { // Check if the combination of email and surveyId already exists
    result.push(entry); 
    set.add(key);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked like a charm!  I tried to use Set but I am kind of a noob and I did not remember of doing this "const getUniqueKey = ({email, surveyId}) => email + "||" + surveyId;"  I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the result that you are looking for is not clear:

For instance, you have for the same email and same surveyId different choices, Why the second is not in the expected results?

```
 {
    email: 'mynewemail@gmail.com',
    surveyId: '1234',
    choice: 'no'
  },

{
    email: 'mynewemail@gmail.com',
    surveyId: '1234',
    choice: 'yes'
  },
```

Comment: So sendGrid send the email with a Survey 1234 with a Yes and No answer. Both answers are Links where an webhook will gather the information. I just want the first answer because I don't want the user to provide multiple answers to the same survey. So although it is expected to receive multiple choices I only care for the first.